# Pushing inserts into SQL Server with C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to insert about 5000 (typically, can be 10K+ at times) rows into SQL Server at a time. My insert statements are generated by a C# program.

One way could be by simply generating a big string full of these SQL statements and then actually making SQL Server execute them using `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` But there is a risk that SQL Server might not be able to execute a big statement like that.

Is there a way I could sort of push the SQL statements to some kind of "SQL Server buffer" (if there is one) and then finally execute them all ?

**EDIT -** I am working with SQL Server 2005, 2008. So, I need something compatible with both.

Thanks.

Comment: Google for "SQL Server mass insert" and you'll find a host of solutions.

Comment: There are better ways to insert thousands of rows into a database than home made (.net, php, coldfusion, doesn't matter) applications, but sometimes it really is necessary to roll your own.  If so, you'll have to add your records one by one.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Thats exactly what I am doing now. I am not sure if row by row is the best way. If I let it go in batches of 5K, 10K etc., then SQL server does not execute those big strings. Probably, a limit on the size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SqlBulkCopy](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/03/01/effective-use-of-sql-bulk-insert.aspx) achieve that goal. I think it will be the best approach

Comment: Yes SqlBulkCopy should be the way to go. Have a look at [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)